# MVC3 and User Management

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, membership, userid

I'm a newbie in .NET framework but have a vast experience in other MVC based frameworks like Symfony and Zend frameworks.

I have an application which requires workshop participants to register and then select workshops they'd like to participate in so I have 3 models i.e. Workshop, Participant and Enrollment which basically has WorkshopID and ParticipantID.

How do i integrate the exisiting Membership or is there any other way to record the ParticipantID into the Enrollments after they've registered and selected their desired workshops? It would've been a one minute thing with Symfony or Zend but cannot figure out how to scaffold the registered users and their selections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to link your participants with membership users the best way is to add a Guid column (userId) to your Participant table and link it with Primary Key on `aspnet_Users` table. That way you link your domain participant with ASP.NET user.

Answer (score -1):

As Jakub points out this a business domain problem. It doesn't look like you are looking to scaffold authorization around the Enrolments which is what I originally assumed. If you were then you would look to the .NET [RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx).

This is tied in with authentication and MembershipProvider, and provides a quick scaffold to group users into security Roles upon registration as follows:

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(User.Identity.Name, "Workshop");
Roles.RemoveUserFromRole(User.Identity.Name, "Workshop");
```

Using a `AspNetSqlRoleProvider` with Sql Server, is more or less out the box, but there is some config and set up associated.

For business domain however, for association between users and Enrolments you would map the 1-to-many using the unique `MembershipUser.ProviderUserKey` (or your own abstraction from this), and keep the Enrolments in your own schema.

[The Entity Framework](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) can be used to help quickly scaffold the database schema from your Models using code-first.

Comment: -1 - I think that mixing security (roles) with application domain (workshops) is a bad decision. The proper one would be to create relevant database tables (Workshops, Participants and linker)

Comment: I would agree - but it does depend on intent of the grouping - he may well be looking for a security based solution as the question asks specifically about membership and it's a valid scenario - I was trying to provide the quick .NET scaffold analogy for grouping users. If the intent is for business domain then no it's not suitable. Actually re-reading the question it does indeed look more like a business domain problem. In fact I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you all for opening my eyes, i think I was approaching this issue with the mentality of how I used to implement the solution in other frameworks.